# how to open airbnb SingleDatePicker calendar on focus

Tags: reactjs

Am trying to include a airbnb SingleDatePicker in my component as shown below

```
import "react-dates/initialize";
import "react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css";
import { SingleDatePicker } from "react-dates";

export default class ExpenseForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      createdAt: moment(),
      calendarFocused: false
    };

    this.onDateChange = this.onDateChange.bind(this);
    this.onFocusChange = this.onFocusChange.bind(this);
  }

  onDateChange(createdAt) {
    this.setState(() => ({ createdAt }));
  }

  onFocusChange({ focused }) {
    this.setState(() => ({
      focused
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SingleDatePicker
            date={this.state.createdAt}
            startDateId="MyDatePicker"
            onDateChange={this.onDateChange}
            focused={this.state.calendarFocused}
            onFocusChange={this.onFocusChange}
            id="SDP"
          />

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It shows the current date inside the inside the input box as shown below but when i click on the field nothing happens(Calendar widget not opening).

[image]

Am not getting any errors in the console to figure out what is the issue. Could anyone please help me on fixing this issue?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are targeting the wrong state key in your `onFocusChange` function. Try changing the function to this:

```
onFocusChange({ focused }) {
  this.setState({ calendarFocused: focused });
}
```

Notice I also removed the anonymous function from inside of your `setState` call. You can remove it from your `onDateChange` function as well:

```
onDateChange(createdAt) {
  this.setState(({ createdAt }));
}
```

I also noticed that you're using the `startDateId` `prop` that is not available for the `SingleDatePicker`. Airbnb uses that for the `DateRangePicker` to determine which `input` to focus on. There is only one `input` in the `SingleDatePicker`, so it does not require that `prop`. You can remove that `prop` without any change to your functionality.

Answer (score 0):

1- correct this handler

```
onFocusChange = ({ focused }) => {
    this.setState(() => ({ calendarFocused: focused }));
  };
```

2- `import 'react-dates/initialize';` //dependency as of v13.0.0

3-since u r not using webpack

Create a CSS file with the contents of require.resolve('react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css') and include it in your html  section.

To see this in action, you can check out https://github.com/majapw/react-dates-demo which adds react-dates on top of a simple create-react-app setup.